# Pig - How to Join and Define Schema in One Step

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata, cloudera

I resort to the following:

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage('\\u001') AS (
    foo:int
    ,bar:chararray
);
B = LOAD 'b.txt' USING PigStorage('\\u001') AS (
    foo:int
    ,baz:long
);
C = JOIN A BY foo, B BY foo;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE
    A::foo AS foo
    ,A::bar AS bar
    ,B::baz AS baz
;
```

How can I join and define the schema in a single step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#join-inner) you can't define a schema when joining relations.
Note:
Syntactically you can nest commands to have the feeling that you saved some steps like:

```
D = foreach
    (join (LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage('\\u001') AS (foo:int ,bar:chararray)) by foo,
          (LOAD 'b.txt' USING PigStorage('\\u001') AS (foo:int ,baz:long)) by foo
    ) generate $0 as foo, $1 as bar, $3 as baz;
```

But I'd avoid doing so. It's chaotic and nonetheless it generates the same explain plan as the original one.